# jquery ui.progressbar label - Change text color on background passing letter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar, jquery-ui-progressbar

I have added a label to the jquery ui progressbar using [this demo](http://jsbin.com/ohiyo).

What I want to do is change the text color depending on if the progress bar is behind the letter.

How can I tell if that has happened?[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its kinda ugly but if you duplicate the label, one outside the bar and one inside, and use `overflow: hidden` you can pull it off:

http://jsbin.com/ohiyo/21/

*Only tested in Chrome dev and firefox 4*

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`change event`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#event-change) of .progressbar like so:

```
updateProgressColor = function() {
  if( $(this).progressbar('percentage').toFixed(0) == 100 ) {
    $(this).css('background', '#F000');
  }
}

$('#progressbar').progressbar({
  change: updateProgressColor
});
```

Comment: that will just update the color if the progressbar has finished, please see my image

Comment: I wouldn't do what you're asking in CSS at all. There is no feasible way to do what you ask in pure CSS and Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (newVal >= 50)
    $('.pblabel').css('color', newColor);
else
    $('.pblabel').css('color', defaultColor);
```

Comment: please see the attached image, I want it to be slightly more precise than that.

Comment: still not exactly what I need, The label could be any text at all, I need to almost find out where each letter is positioned relative to its parent...

Comment: its stupid, in the early release of progressbar they actually had this in there, but they took it out :/